# How to get the HTML rendering result in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, rendering

I would like to know is this possible to get HTML rendering result using JS? Let me specify the question a little bit, a HTML file may also contain CSS / JS, which modify the final result of the web page, also, the rendering engine of the browser may be different as well. If the page successfully rendered, is this possible for me to transfer a page to a programme readable format? Any advise? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to refer to use a javascript framewrok to generate your program, there is lot of framework that write completly in JS like :

```
Google Web Toolkit
Ember.js
MooTools
```

here is a wikipedia link for comparison : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks

if you want to générate a program without any webbrowser you have two ways :

1. make your program as a website and finaly create with c#.net or
   vb.net or just vb6 a simple program with internal browser that get
   full size of window, this is used in some programs like for example
   : skype.
2. second way, is to rename your `index.html` file to `program.hta` you
       should read about hta applications :) this a great way